# Книга по Java в Web

Tags: java, книги

Доброго времени суток, гуглил до посинения но так и не нашел ничего толкового по данному вопросу кроме единичной книги "Электронный магазин на Java и XML", но это немного не то, да и книге уже немало лет...

Cобственно подскажите есть ли нормальная литература по сабжу, можно на английском, можно даже просто кучу документации и т.д. Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вот [тут](http://java-course.ru/students/students.php) можно почитать

Comment: Спасибо, пошел курить :)

Comment: Погуглите GWT, SmartGWT (клиентская (браузер) часть), Java servlet - серверная. Вообще, по серверной части (http и проч.) книг полно.

Comment: Верно. Вот еще ссылка: [вопросы про GWT на hashcode.ru][1].


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/tagged/gwt/

Comment: @Angry Bird, не соглашусь насчет тормозов.